# Cappuccino, Spoutcore or Homegrown solution for web based drawing application?

Tags: javascript, entity-relationship, sproutcore, cappuccino

I'm currently looking at building an application for drawing entity relationships (data models).

Looking at both Sproutcore and Cappuccino they both look beefy enough to handle that kind of thing (see 280 slides for cappuccino example)...

Ideally I need a framework which lets users drag and drop components and then link them together and then when the user is done to be able to "freeze dry" these objects as JSON ready to be stored in some kind of database so they can be loaded again...

Which of the mentioned frameworks are more geared towards that already?

Or is the easiest to extend in the places where its lacking?

Or would it be easier in the long run to make my own using jQuery/prototype?

Answer (score 5):

280Slides is a great real world example of what you can do as far as drawing goes, those shapes are obviously predefined, but you can draw whatever you want using our first class Graphics library (CoreGraphics). This means you also get most of the features you get in Canvas, but they also work in IE.

Atlas also does the linking together of components.

GoMockingbird is also a good example of an applications where you can easily lay out components.

The simple floor plan demo (with a tutorial) 
http://cappuccino.org/learn/demos/FloorPlan/index-deploy.html 
also gives you a good sense of the cool things you can do with first class drawing support.

Comment: Thanks @Me1000 My only gripe with cappuccino at the moment is the lack of adoption.. Sproutcore has one deffinate big company backing it: Apple(mobileme and iwork.com) and im struggling desperately to find many cappuccino tutorials (so if you have any others hit me up!)

Comment: Remember that Cappuccino has quite a few pubic apps out there. Compared to the number of public SC apps out there I think Cappuccino has the upper hand for now. There are a lot of tutorials posted here: http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/ including links to other sites with more tutorials and some more listed here: https://github.com/280north/cappuccino/wiki/Cappuccino-Tutorials Additionally there are a LOT of people around on the mailing list and IRC channel that are more than happy to help you if you have questions. You're always welcome to ping me personally.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Sproutcore demo:  http://demo.sproutcore.com/family_tree/ -- that seems pretty close to what you are describing.

note that this demo uses some external frameworks; its not just Sproutcore.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks! Thats pretty much the behaviour i was looking for.. thanks!